# Not Understand how this Canvas Code Works

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm playing around with Canvas Code. I wrote a function that draws out a path

```
  function draw_faces() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("faces_bkgd");
    if (canvas.getContext) {
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      var happy_face = new Path2D();
      happy_face.rect(10,10,100,100);
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,200)";
      ctx.fill(happy_face);

      happy_face.moveTo(50,50);
      happy_face.lineTo(90,90);
      happy_face.lineTo(90,50);

      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
      ctx.fill(happy_face);

      ctx.save();
      ctx.translate(50,50);
      ctx.fillStyle="rgb(0,200,0)";
      ctx.fill(happy_face);
      ctx.restore();
    }
```

[image]

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/st7r4mzb/)

It gives me the following output at the top left of the page, there is a red square with a blue triangle in it. To the bottom of the red square, there is a overlapping green square with a triangle cutout.

Why is it a green square with a triangle cutout instead of a green square with a blue triangle in it?

Also, what do you guys use to debug Canvas on Web Inspector for Safari?

Comment: So are you saying that you want the blue triangle to be inside the green square instead of where it is currently?

Comment: it is the way the path is defined, the fill takes place following the path, so as the path is defined, the fill might take place *inside* or *outside* the path, try changing the ordering of the `happy_face` path

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/el/docs/Web/API/Path2D

Comment: @NikosM. Are you saying that the fill affects the path? So if I make 3 `fills`, then my path has 3 `fills` to it?

Comment: @JessicaGu, not exactly rather the path affects the fill, the fill depends on the path and how this is defined, but the already given answer provides a much better analysis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: I created some images explaining step by step what is happening. If you would like me to go into more detail please let me know. If there are certain parts you do not understand please let me know. If there are terms (methods, etc) that don't make sense let me know. Anything vague let me know. :)

[image]
[image]

---

Here are the important parts of you code with comments on what really is happening.

First part of your code draws a blue square with an instance of Path2D that you have defined as a rect.

```
     var happy_face = new Path2D();
     happy_face.rect(10, 10, 100, 100);
     ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,200)";
     ctx.fill(happy_face);
```

Then instead of creating a new instance of Path2D, you use your previous variable, `happy_face`, that is still defined as a *rect* and now you cut out a triangle and set the color to red and draw it.

```
     //The moveTo and lineTo cut out a triangle in your square.
     happy_face.moveTo(50, 50);
     happy_face.lineTo(90, 90);
     happy_face.lineTo(90, 50);

     ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
     ctx.fill(happy_face);
```

Since you didn't move this square with a triangle cut out in it, you draw on top of your blue square. This gives the impression the triangle you cut out is blue, but that's just the old square underneath.

Going to ignore the save and restore methods since they don't do anything worthwhile. You then do a tanslate.. which just moves the pointer from where you start drawing from (0,0) to (50, 50). At ths point you change colors from red to green and you start drawing at (50, 50) happy_face ( the old square with a triangle cut out in it ).

```
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(50,50);
  ctx.fillStyle="rgb(0,200,0)";
  ctx.fill(happy_face);
  ctx.restore();
```

Unfortunately you can't debut "canvas". Because when you draw something, you can't just move it. It's literally drawn on the canvas. If you draw a square on top of the other square, well the previous square is lost.

Comment: So if I get what you mean, I moved the origin of `happy_face` but not `ctx`. So then a red square was drawn over the blue square. Also, the Path figure is also affected by actions after your first `fill` ( I thought it was only before the first `fill`). Also did not know that `lineTo` can cut a triangle on something I had already made. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by ` If you draw a square on top of the other square, well the previous square is lost.`. So if I ask for `happy_face`, I only get the green square (I have lost access to the red and blue squares)? If so, I thought the restore would get me back to the original `happy_face`.

Comment: @JessicaGu think of an HTML canvas as a IRL canvas. When you draw something on a canvas, let it dry, and draw something on top of that... well the parts you draw on become lost because the new drawing is covering the old one and nothing you do can bring back the old drawing. The same thing occurs in an HTML canvas.

Comment: @JessicaGu for comprehension purposes I will draw you an image explaining the steps. Check the post monday. ^^

Comment: Sorry >.< New to stack overflow. But what do you mean by "check the post monday"? Where is that?

Comment: @JessicaGu just means I don't have time to update my answer and you should come back Monday to see if the updated answer. xD

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful :) One more question though :O For ```     happy_face.moveTo(50, 50);
     happy_face.lineTo(90, 90);
     happy_face.lineTo(90, 50);```, even thought I don't do a fill or stroke, this will still cut out a triangle for me? is it possible to add a line so that it places an orange triangle there? Or would I have to instead create a Path2d object that is a triangle and then fill it out orange?

Comment: @JessicaGu you have to remember you defined happy_face to be a rectangle. You either have to create a new Path2D object or you could simply change the first blue square to an orange square. ;)